# Two different text input with datepicker based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group date xdue_date datepicker1">
          <input type="text" id="ap_due_date" name="ap_due_date/">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group date xdue_date2 datepicker2" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" id="ap_due_date2" name="ap_due_date"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="ap_status" name="ap_status">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="2">3</option>
        <option value="2">4</option>
        <option value="2">5</option>
      </select>
    </div>

<script>

    $('#ap_status').change(function() {
        var ap_status = $(this).val();
        $('.xdue_date').hide();
        $('.xdue_date2').hide();

        if (ap_status == 1) {
            $('.xdue_date2').show();
            $('.xdue_date').hide();
        } else if (ap_status == 2) {
            $('.xdue_date').show();
            $('.xdue_date2').hide();
        } else if (ap_status == 3) {
            $('.xdue_date').show();
            $('.xdue_date2').hide();
        } else if (ap_status == 4) {
            $('.xdue_date2').show();
            $('.xdue_date').hide();
        } else if (ap_status == 5) {
            $('.xdue_date').show();
            $('.xdue_date2').hide();

        }
    });

    $(function(){
        $('.datepicker1').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            //startDate: '-0m'
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            //$('#sDate1').text($('.datepicker1').data('date'));
            $('.datepicker1').datepicker('hide');
        });

        $('.datepicker2').datepicker({
            format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            startDate: '-0m'
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            $('#sDate1').text($('.datepicker2').data('date'));
            $('.datepicker2').datepicker('hide');
        });

    });

</script>
```

I have one text input and one dropdown. If I'll select = 2, the other text input is visible, the other one is hide. My problem now is to get a correct dates. Because now if both input fields have dates, when I'll save the value of ap_due_date is base on the first input fields.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: hi Mayank Patel, I need to have a correct value of dates, if I'll select ap_status value 2.

Comment: currently what is problem?if you select option 2 but when you save form first datepicker date getting saved?

Comment: If I save the value of Dates that i get is wrong, because if the same fields have the value of dates. the one visible and hidden. I get the value of the first input fields not the one I choose.

Comment: can you show me your save logic?

Comment: Example: If I'll select option 1 with value date of '2017-01-01', but when I'll save I get the value of option 2 which date of '2017-01-05'.

Comment: are you using ajax call to save form?

Comment: @Paul M Bactin if my answer is accepted then see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) how to accept answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add attribute 'disabled' on select option to desired input field.  input field with attribute `disabled`, is not submitted.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/2783/)

Js

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    alert($(this).serialize())
    })
    $('#ap_due_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altField: '#thealtdate',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
    $('#ap_due_date2').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        altField: '#thealtdate',
        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });

    $('select').on('change',function(){
            if($(this).val()==1){
            $("#xdue_date2").hide()
          $("#ap_due_date2").prop('disabled',true)
          $("#ap_due_date").prop("disabled", false);
          $("#xdue_date").show()
        }
        if($(this).val()==2){
            $("#xdue_date2").show()
          $("#ap_due_date2").prop("disabled", false);
          $("#ap_due_date").prop('disabled',true)
          $("#xdue_date").hide()
        }
    })

});
```

html

```
<form action="" id="test">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="input-group date xdue_date datepicker1" id="xdue_date">
        <input type="text" id="ap_due_date" name="ap_due_date" placeholder="first">
      </div>
      <div class="input-group date xdue_date2 datepicker2" id="xdue_date2" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" id="ap_due_date2" name="ap_due_date" disabled placeholder="second" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <select id="ap_status" name="ap_status">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in your code is you have given same name attribute for both of your textboxes.

So when you toggle between textboxes only first date picker date is getting saved.

Solution: when you save you form to check for dropdown values and if value is 1 then save with first datepicker name attribute if 2nd selected then use different name for value.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="input-group date xdue_date datepicker1">
          <input type="text" id="ap_due_date" name="ap_due_date/">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group date xdue_date2 datepicker2" style="display:none;">
          <input type="text" id="ap_due_date2" name="ap_due_date2"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

When dropdown value is 1 save date using `ap_due_date` name and when dropdown value is 2 save date using `ap_due_date2` attribute in your form.

Because form must have unique attribute name for each element.
**EDIT:**
So in your form submit method use if condition

```
if(ap_status == 1)
  //save ap_due_date value in ap_due_date
else if() apc_status == 2
  // save ap_due_date2 value in ap_due_date
```

Comment: but in database should save only in ap_due_date.

Comment: by the way you are using ajax call to save form if you show your save logic I can so you workaround?

Comment: no, im not using ajax for this. can you give me an example to do that sir? in my controller it look like this : $data['ap_due_date'] = $this->input->post('ap_due_date'); Example I select dropdown option 2 which save using ap_due_date2. How do save that in my database ap_due_date?

Comment: are u using form submit to save your form?

Comment: Yah im using form submit.

Comment: ok are you getting your dropdown value using ap_status in form submit method?

Comment: Thank You for that Mayank Patel. I try that later.

Comment: can you share fiddle?